# Create MBtiles from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

I'm using GeoServer version of 2.7.1.1 and installed plugin for MB tiles, now I want to know how to generate MBtiles after installing the plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to use geoserver to publish mbtiles. there are many other softwares that can do same very easily. I would suggest go for tilemill. but here is list feel free to explore.

https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/wiki/Implementations

Comment: But if you already have a WMS, and you also want to offer MBtiles, why set up another service?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [full documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/output.html) before going into production, but the short answer is you change the format parameter of your WMS request to be `format=mbtiles`.

If you need to produce a larger set of tiles then you probably want to explore the [WPS mbtiles](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/mbtiles/output.html#mbtiles-wps-process) service.

Comment: Thanks iant,
where should i change the format parameter?

Comment: in the getmap request  you are sending the server

Comment: am sorry iant,Can you explain in detail,am new to this,where i have to change anything in .xml file?

Comment: http://localhost:8088/geoserver/wms?
request=GetMap
&service=WMS
&version=1.1.1
&layers=topp%3Astates
&styles=population
&srs=EPSG%3A4326
&bbox=-145.15104058007,21.731919794922,-57.154894212888,58.961058642578&
&width=780
&height=330
**&format=image/mbtiles**
&tileset_name=topp%3Astates
&min_zoom=0
&max_zoom=5
&min_column=1
&max_column=2
&min_row=1
&max_row=2
&zoom level=1
&column=2
&rows=2
&gridset=EPSG:4326

Comment: @ iant, i have doubt in **&format=image/mbtiles** , is this correct syntax also in  **&gridset=EPSG:4326**

Comment: from the documentation you can leave the gridset out for the default, otherwise you can put in any of the gridsets you have set up for that layer and SRS combination

Comment: taht is ok ,even am not getting the mbtiles when i write like this **&format=image/mbtile**
is this correct?

Comment: please read the documentation - format=mbtiles

Answer (score 0):

This is the right request for generating mbtiles from geoserver :

```
http:/Server_Ip:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=MyLayer&transparent=true&styles=&bbox=-17.64404,-1.0,0.54932,36.90597&srs=EPSG:4326&format_options=min_zoom:3;max_zoom:20&width=368&height=768&format=mbtiles
```